# Auto Focus Lamp: Nikon

Tags: autofocus, front-focus

I don't know what happened but my AF lamp doesn't work any more. The bulb is not burnt out because it flickers when \i tested it with the 10 second timer. The problem comes when I'm trying to find focus in the dark, it doesn't come on which made my job very difficult last week. I have changed the mode to AF-S but still nothing, someone told me to 'select the center point' i'm not sure what that means. Please help, I have a gig in two weeks & the lamp makes life so much easier.

Also my lenses on the d5100 don't do that flexing acting any more when they are on auto im so stressed. Pleasde help.

Answer (score 3):

See your camera manual for the situations when the AF-Assist illumination does not work.  It does not work in Live View mode. It does not work unless you have the center focus point selected. Does not work if continuous focus is selected (so use AF-S). There is a menu A2 where it can simply be turned off.

Also AF-Assist does not work in Manual focus mode, so if you have turned AF off, that might also explain your "no flexing" (if that means attempts to auto focus).

Page 41 of the D5100 Reference Manual specifies this and more.  The Reference manual is a larger more complete manual that is free at https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/23/D5100.html
Search the PDF manual for the word Assist.